# Make table data multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem with the results I get, I try to get data from my database and I want to make all data dynamic, so for the "header" table I have to get it from the database, and for "body" I want to get it from the database also depends in "header_id". The results of the "body" obtained should be from left to right not from top to bottom.

as you can see my results be like this
[image]

but this should be like this

[image]

can someone help me? this is my view code.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($du_head as $key => $value) {
                echo "<th>".$value->duh_judul."</th>";
            }

         ?>
             th>Aksi</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
         <?php foreach ($du_head as $key => $value) { ?>
         <tr>
         <?php
             $q = $this->db->query("select * from data_umum where duh_id = '$value->duh_id'")->result();
                 foreach ($q as $ac) {
                     echo "<td>".$ac->duh_isi."</td>";
                     echo "<td><i class='fa fa-trash'><a href=''></a></i></td>";
                 }
             ?>
         </tr>
     <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this my array results for `du_head`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#38 (3) {
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["maplink_id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["duh_judul"]=>
    string(10) "Nama Jalan"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#39 (3) {
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["maplink_id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["duh_judul"]=>
    string(13) "Panjang Jalan"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#40 (3) {
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["maplink_id"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["duh_judul"]=>
    string(5) "Lebar"
  }
}
```

and this my array from `$q`

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#103 (4) {
    ["du_id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["du_kode"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["duh_isi"]=>
    string(14) "Jalan Komering"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#104 (4) {
    ["du_id"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["du_kode"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["duh_isi"]=>
    string(16) "Panjang 50 Meter"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#105 (4) {
    ["du_id"]=>
    string(2) "17"
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["du_kode"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["duh_isi"]=>
    string(14) "Lebar 10 Meter"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#106 (4) {
    ["du_id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["du_kode"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["duh_isi"]=>
    string(14) "jalan nasional"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#107 (4) {
    ["du_id"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["du_kode"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["duh_isi"]=>
    string(2) "P3"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(stdClass)#108 (4) {
    ["du_id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["duh_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["du_kode"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["duh_isi"]=>
    string(2) "L2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you want each row to be be a new table column, you'll want to put the foreach inside the `<td>` and not the `<tr>`.

Also, you probably don't need to do that query inside the foreach if you're already getting `du_head` from a query. You can just add `duh_isi` to the select if part of the same table, or if not just do a join.

Also, you should use a PHP framework. This will allow you to separate your database query logic from the html templating logic, and provide an ORM to sanitize your database inputs, both critical things to secure and maintainable code.

Comment: Have you try it ? I don't think you understand what I want.

Comment: @RizalTerrisElvalino I don't have your database scheme or the rest of your code to try it myself, but I encourage you to try my idea of putting the foreach between td instead of tr. If you haven't tried that yet, try it and let me know the results and how it's not what you expect and then that'll help me understand what you want, if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'have to post it in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515669/query-order-by-and-grouping-by @Goose

Answer (score 0):

You have your column and row loops logic mixed up, try to map it into an array first :

```
$rows = [];
$additional_column = count($du_head); // count the columns to get the last column index for displaying the delete button
foreach ($du_head as $colkey => $value) { 
    $q = $this->db->query("select * from data_umum where duh_id = '$value->duh_id'")->result();
    foreach ($q as $rowkey => $ac) {
        $rows[$rowkey][$colkey] = "<td>" . $ac->duh_isi . "</td>";
    }
    $rows[$colkey][$additional_column] = "<td>" . $ac->duh_isi . "</td>";
}
```

Then you could display the rows over a `foreach` loop again :

```
foreach ($rows as $rowkey => $row) {
    echo "<tr>"; // print each table row
    foreach ($row as $colkey => $col) {
        echo $col; // print each table column
    }
    echo "<td><i class='fa fa-trash'><a href='" . site_url("controller/delete/$rowkey") . "'></a></i></td>"; // print each delete button, adjust it to whatever you need
    echo "</tr>\r\n";
}
```

Put it together and it will be like :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($du_head as $key => $value) {
                echo "<th>" . $value->duh_judul . "</th>";
            }

            ?>
            <th>Aksi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php 
        $rows = [];
        $additional_column = count($du_head); // count the column total to get the last column index for displaying the delete button
        foreach ($du_head as $colkey => $value) { 
            $q = $this->db->query("select * from data_umum where duh_id = '$value->duh_id'")->result();
            foreach ($q as $rowkey => $ac) {
                $rows[$rowkey][$colkey] = "<td>" . $ac->duh_isi . "</td>";
            }
            $rows[$colkey][$additional_column] = "<td>" . $ac->duh_isi . "</td>";
        }

        foreach ($rows as $rowkey => $row) {
            echo "<tr>"; // print each table row
            foreach ($row as $colkey => $col) {
                echo $col; // print each table column
            }
            echo "<td><i class='fa fa-trash'><a href='" . site_url("controller/delete/$rowkey") . "'></a></i></td>"; // print each delete button, adjust it to whatever you need
            echo "</tr>\r\n";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this is absolutely weird since you are mixing up the query inside a loop and inside a *template view*, you should consider using PHP framework to prevent further frustration.